# Spark 2.0: How to list or remove dirs and files in s3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, operating-system

Is there any way to list files and dirs, remove files and dirs, check if a dir exists, etc directly from spark 2.0 shell?

I am able to use os python library but it just 'sees' local dirs, not s3.

I have also found this but I cannot make it work
http://bigdatatech.taleia.software/2015/12/21/check-if-exists-a-amazon-s3-path-from-apache-spark/

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use s3cmd http://s3tools.org/s3cmd-howto , in order to use it inside python, you'll need to use os.system or os.subprocess

List your buckets again with s3cmd ls

```
   ~$ s3cmd ls
   2007-01-19 01:41  s3://logix.cz-test
```

Upload a file into the bucket

```
   ~$ s3cmd put addressbook.xml s3://logix.cz-test/addrbook.xml
   File 'addressbook.xml' stored as s3://logix.cz-test/addrbook.xml (123456 bytes)
```

Another options is using tinys3 lib https://www.smore.com/labs/tinys3/

Another option is using simples3 http://sendapatch.se/projects/simples3/

```
s = S3Bucket(bucket, access_key=access_key, secret_key=secret_key)
print s  
<S3Bucket ... at 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/...'>
```

Comment: How could I use s3cmd tools from spark shell? I do not think it is possible.

Thanks

Comment: @Techzak if I answer your question, please accept it :)

Comment: sorry it is now